# Callback with parameters with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, callback, kotlin

I just started Kotlin so please be nice :)

I have a class that is responsible for fetching some data and notify the main activity that its need to update its UI.

So i have made a function in my DataProvider.kt :

```
      fun getPeople(fromNetwork: Boolean, results: ((persons: Array<Person>, error: MyError?) -> Unit)) {

        // do some stuff stuff
        val map = hashMapOf(
                "John" to "Doe",
                "Jane" to "Smith"
        )

        var p = Person(map)
        val persons: Array <Person> = arrayOf (p)
        results(persons, null)
    }
```

So i want to call this from my activity but i can't find the right syntax ! :

```
    DataProvider.getPeople(
            true,
            results =
    )
```

I have try many things but i just want to get my array of persons and my optional error so i can update the UI.

The goal is to perform async code in my data provider so my activity can wait for it.

Any ideas ? Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This really depends on how you define the callback method. If you use a standalone function, use the `::` operator. First (of course), I should explain the syntax:

```
(//these parenthesis are technically not necessary
(persons: Array<Person>, error: MyError?)//defines input arguments: an Array of Person and a nullable MyError
     -> Unit//defines the return type: Unit is the equivalent of void in Java (meaning no return type)
)
```

So the method is defined as:

```
fun callback(persons: Array<CustomObject>, error: Exception?){
    //Do whatever
}
```

And you call it like:

```
DataProvider.getPeople(
    true,
    results = this::callback
)
```

However, if you use anonymous callback functions, it's slightly different. This uses lambda as well:

```
getPeople(true, results={/*bracket defines a function. `persons, error` are the input arguments*/persons, error ->  {
        //do whatever
    }})
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much, can you tell me what is the difference between an anonymous callback functions & a standlaone function ? Which one is better ?

Comment: There isn't really one that's better than the other, which you use really depends on which you prefer, and if you're going to be using it elsewhere. If you're going to write the code multiple times or call the method as a non-callback method (or as a callback for a different call), use standalone methods. Otherwise use anonymous functions. There aren't really any "rules" on it though (these are just my personal preferences), so you can basically pick whichever you like

Answer (score 4):

Yes Kotlin has a great way of using callback functions which I will show you an example of how I use them below:

```
fun addMessageToDatabase(message: String, fromId: String, toId: String,
                                addedMessageSuccessHandler: () -> Unit,
                                addedMessageFailureHandler: () -> Unit) {



    val latestMessageRef = mDatabase.getReference("/latest-messages/$fromId/$toId")
    latestMessageRef.setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener {
        latestMessageUpdateSuccessHandler.invoke()

    }.addOnFailureListener {
        latestMessageUpdateFailureHandler.invoke()
    }
}
```

And finally you can utilise the new callbacks with the following code

```
databaseManager.updateLatestMessageForUsers(message, fromId, toId,
        latestMessageUpdateSuccessHandler = {
            // your success action
        },
        latestMessageUpdateFailureHandler = {
            // your failure action
        })
```

So basically when I successfully add a new row to my database I'm invoking a success or a failure response to the caller of the service. Hopefully this will help out someone.